# Using both OnTouchListener and OnClickListener

Tags: java, android

I have a recyclerview. After setting adapter, user should be reorder their list and save it. And afterwards it should be populate like saved one. But onclicking list items, it color has to change and one of item will open a popup. I've write my codes, but when i add both onclick and ontouch, neither of them worked. If i comment one of them, they work fine. How can i solve this?

```
        holder.itemView.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> {
        if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            touchHelper.startDrag(holder);
        }
        return false;
    });


    holder.clData.setOnLongClickListener(view -> {
        row_index = position;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        return true;
    });

    if (row_index == position) {
        holder.clData.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_back));
        holder.txtAmount.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    } else {
        holder.clData.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.darkestGrey));
        holder.txtAmount.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_current));
    }
    /// https://github.com/sjthn/RecyclerViewDemo/blob/advanced-usecases/app/src/main/java/com/example/srijith/recyclerviewdemo/SwipeAndDragHelper.java
    ////// My Adapter 
     AdapterDatas adapter = new AdapterDatas (context, lstDatas);
        SwipeAndDragHelper swipeAndDragHelper = new SwipeAndDragHelper(adapter);
        ItemTouchHelper touchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(swipeAndDragHelper);
        adapter.setTouchHelper(touchHelper);
        rvDatas.setAdapter(adapter);
        touchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(rvDatas);
```

Comment: do you get any error?

Comment: nope not error. It just wont working both enabled